# How to check how many member are in a voice channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Is there a way to check how many members are in a voice channel or if it's empty in discord.js (V. 13.8.1)?

I have already tried this

```js
async function usercount(voiceState){
    let users = await(voiceState.channel.fetch.memberCount);
    console.log(users)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`VoiceChannel#members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=members) is a collection of the members in a voice-based channel. Collection's have a `size` property, so something like this should work:

```js
function usercount(voiceState) {
  let { members } = voiceState.channel;

  console.log(members);

  return members.size;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can use the `VoiceChannel.members.size` to get how many members are in the channel.

Here's an example:

```
const GuildMember = new Discord.GuildMember(); // This shall be the command author.

if (GuildMember.voice.channel) 
{      
    console.log(GuildMember.voice.channel.members.size);
};
```

Comment: `new Discord.GuildMember` is not the command author and this code will likely throw a `TypeError` as `voice` will be `undefined`.